# Failed Google Earth Install?

Tags: deb, google-earth

Attempted to install google-earth-stable 6.2.from the google earth downloads. So i have a broken package and a new download in the DL file.

Synaptic and Software Centre lockup so i cannot fix the package, un-install, re-install.

What's next?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first.  Open the terminal and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-earth-stable
```

Now, that takes care of uninstalling Google Earth.  Next, let's add a Google Earth PPA Repository to your system:

In the terminal, copy and paste these commands:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add 

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable
```

Now you won't have to worry about your Google Earth getting out of date.  Now that you have this repository, updates to Google earth will come alongside your other system updates.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You Dean, I pressed on and cleared all references to Google Earth by using the file search. Gave myself permission to edit out the references and installed a new download through the terminal. That has cleared Synaptic and USC, and i think i have a working installation of Google Earth and the Google earth Repository. Your first command did not find Google on my machine! SOLVED though, Thank you again!

Comment: @MatthewRees - if you are happy with the answer, please click the tick button next to the answer to mark as accepted and to close the thread. Thanks.